# Sub Partitioning in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning

I need to partition table date wise and then this partition needs to be sub partition by userid.
I have partition table like below:

```
ALTER TABLE sentbox1 PARTITION BY RANGE(to_days(CreatedDateTime))(
PARTITION p20161130 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2016-11-30')),
PARTITION p20161201 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2016-12-01'))
);
```

Now,How to add sub partition by userid  into partitions 'p20161130' and 'p20161201'.

Answer (score 4):

I tested this on MySQL 8.0.0-dmr:

```
ALTER TABLE sentbox1 
PARTITION BY RANGE(to_days(CreatedDateTime)) 
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(userid) 
SUBPARTITIONS 4 (
  PARTITION p20161130 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2016-11-30')),
  PARTITION p20161201 VALUES LESS THAN (to_days('2016-12-01'))
);
```

Note that subpartitioning works only with HASH or KEY as the partitioning method.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning-subpartitions.html for more information.

---

Re comment from Rick:

@RickJames, I think you know that depends entirely on whether the query one run aligns with the partitioning and subpartitioning. If your query logic causes the query to span subpartitions, it gives no benefit.

I did confirm that partition pruning heeds conditions on the subpartition key.

When I put a condition only on the major partition key, it has to scan all subpartitions of that partition:

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from sentbox1 
    where createddatetime = from_days(736663) \G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sentbox1
   partitions: p20161201_p20161201sp0,
               p20161201_p20161201sp1,
               p20161201_p20161201sp2,
               p20161201_p20161201sp3
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

When I additionally specify a condition on the `userid` (the subpartition key), we see a decreased subset of subpartitions to be examined:

```
mysql> explain partitions select * from sentbox1 
    where createddatetime = from_days(736663) and userid=3\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: sentbox1
   partitions: p20161201_p20161201sp3 
         type: ALL
possible_keys: NULL
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
```

Comment: You tested it, but did you determine that there is any Performance advantage to either `HASH` or `SUBPARTITION`?  (I present this as a challenge to you, Bill.)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the answer to a question is "don't".  I have yet to find any use for `SUBPARTITION`.  Please explain the use case where you think this will help.

In particular, partitioning does not intrinsically provide any performance benefit.

The usual use case for `BY RANGE(TO_DAYS(..))` is when you need to delete 'old' data.  Doing `DROP PARTITION` is significantly more efficient than `DELETE`.  Is that the case you have?  If so, having `SUBPARTITIONs` does not help in any way that I know of.

Meanwhile, I have found *no* use case for `HASH`.  Sure, it may do pruning on `userid`, but that pruning is no better than having `userid` at the start of a composite index.  And it is likely to be worse.

[*More discussion of Partitioning*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint).